# Team foul but not a personal foul

Tags: rules, officiating, basketball

When are team fouls not person fouls? Is it correct that offensive fouls are not considered personal? Are there are other such fouls? Also is if you have one technical and one flagrant 1 is that an ejection?

Answer (score 2):

In the NBA, an offensive foul is a personal foul but not a team foul.  It also may not lead to free throws for the other team.

There is no rule that combines a flagrant 1 and a technical foul.  The reasoning is that the NBA has a technical foul and a personal foul.  Flagrant fouls are part of the personal fouls, and technical fouls are their own definition.

[NBA Rule 12](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_12.html?nav=ArticleList)

I am not familiar with the other levels of basketball, but I would imagine they are similar.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foul_%28basketball%29) offensive fouls are personal fouls.

> A personal foul against a player of the team in possession of the ball
>   is called an offensive foul.

What I understand from the article is that a team foul relates to the foul count against a team;

> A team foul is any foul by reference to the count against a given team.

Regarding ejections;

> The NBA and NCAA define a Flagrant-1 foul as unnecessary contact, and
>   two such penalties leads to ejection of the player. A Flagrant-2 foul
>   is contact that is both unnecessary and excessive, and requires
>   ejection.

Nowhere in the [rules](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_12.html?nav=ArticleList) does it state that 1 technical and 1 flagrant-1 foul will lead to an ejection (instead you need two of them). As I understand it you can commit 1 of each without facing an ejection.

Comment: I understand 2 flagrant-1 fouls is an ejection. My question is whether one flagrant-1 foul and one technical foul constitutes an ejection. i.e. can a player with a flagrant-1 and one technical continue to play.

Comment: Ok I added that to the answer, as far as I can tell there is no rule about that. You can commit 1 of each without facing an ejection.